What kind of gear system is best for converting a lowering stone to rotation?
Say 100kg stone is lifted to 1 m.
The stone is supposed to lose its potential energy in a way that it turns the gears as the stone moves down.
What kind of gear system (or other system) would it be if it didn't hang in any way but rather was supported from below? I know there is not much energy involved, but this is about the basic concept.
It should allow the stone to go down in a controlled manner so that its energy is converted into rapid rotational motion.

a static push doesn't move.  A dropping stone isn't static

"support from below"? so a rack and pinion... Your use of "static" is very confusing, a "static" lever - is this one that never moves?

A stone drops in a vacuum at a constant velocity- seems static enough in its inertial frame of reference. The concept of hanging vs not seems a bit restrictive though- to avoid having a mechanism be above the weight in descent at any time means a telescoping mechanism is required. Of telescoping mechanisms, a piston might be a common one. Put your rock on a hydraulic piston and do whatever with the fluid to make it flow at a constant rate.

@Abel, can you explain "A stone drops in a vacuum at a constant velocity..."?

@Abel so no acceleration due to gravity ?

If you negate the force due to gravity by making it do work for you, it becomes a moving system that can still be considered "static" so a dropping stone can still be static. Either way: "Someone is wrong on the internet!"

Here is a possible solution. Sorry for the poor diagram.
The rock is on a platform attached to a chain in a manner keeping it horizontal. The chain runs around two gear wheels. A third gear wheel is used to drive whatever apparatus you want to use to extract energy. (and also to raise the rock)
The drive wheel needs to be attached to a gear box to increase rpm to whatever motor you use. This will also cause the decent to be slower.

Another possibility, if you want it supported directly from below, is to use a hydraulic ram. A hydraulic pump will work in reverse as a motor, though there may be a check valve you have to remove. The efficiency will not be very high, maybe 50% - 60% over the duty cycle.
